# обратный список умножить на 10 и на -10

Tags: python, list

есть список lst нужно вывести:

1. lst_new = [90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20]
2. lst_new = [ -80, -70, -60, -50, -40, -30]

   ```
   lst = [2, 3, 4, 5 ,6, 7, 8, 9]
   lst_new = (lst[::-1])# здесь выстраиваю в обратном порядке
   print(lst_new)# здесь нужно вывести умноженное на 10
   ```

Comment: `print(list(map(lambda i: i*10, lst_new)))`

Comment: `list(map((10).__mul__, lst_new))` :)

Comment: а как быть со вторым условием?

Comment: `print(list(map(lambda i: i*-10, lst_new))[1:-1])`

Comment: спасибо. теперь бы разобраться что такое map и lambda в уроке такого не было(

Answer (score 2):

так:

```
lst_new = []
for i in lst[::-1]:
    lst_new.append(i * 10)
print(lst_new) 

lst_new = []
for i in lst[-2:0:-1]:
    lst_new.append(-i * 10)
print(lst_new)
```

тоже самое но в одну строку:

```
lst_new = [i * 10 for i in lst[::-1]]
print(lst_new)

lst_new = [-i * 10 for i in lst[-2:0:-1]]
print(lst_new)
```